# find: unknown predicate

Tags: bash, find

This is probably not a Ubuntu question as such, but a Linux one instead, still hope some Linux user out there can help me understand this.

I'm trying to use the ***find*** command to look for some files an a directory tree.

Unfortunately some of the files are named beginning with a dash, like `-000.jpg`, `-002.jpg`, `00n.jpg` and  so on.
However, every time that the command locates one of the files named that way, it just interrupts the process and complains in the following way:

```
find: unknown predicate `-001.jpg'
```

or whatever the file beginning with a dash is named.

It seems to me that somehow the ***find*** command is interpreting the resulting filename as an argument, but I haven't found a way to circumvent this behavior.

Thanks in advance for sharing your wisdom.

Comment: This is strange behavior and probably [a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)...but I wonder if what's going on is that you have an expression with wildcards in your `find` command itself that is being expanded by the shell into filenames starting with `-` (before it is given to `find`). Can you edit your question to add the full and exact text of the `find` command you're issuing, which is producing this problem?

Comment: What is the exact command line you are using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you quote the patterns you provide to `find`, otherwise the shell may expand them if there are matching files in the current dir.

```
find /some/dir -name *.jpg   # bad
find /some/dir -name "*.jpg" # good
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind.

Comment: I just did `find ~/folder -name "*.png"` and got the error stated in the title.

Comment: @isomorphismes, that line will not produce that error message on its own. It must be caused by other factors. E.g. if you try to put the find command in a variable, then run that variable, that is a plausible way to get that type of error. If that's the case, the solution is simple; don't put commands in variables.

Comment: I accidentally restarted my computer in the last two days and it works now, so I guess I can't reproduce the problem or test it any longer. I can't think of what would have changed but it wasn't using a variable. I just ran the naked line.

Comment: It may have been that I used `find /some/dir -name="*.jpg"` with a `=` instead of a space. HTH some googler.